# How does Haruki know what her ability is?

Tags: sagrada-reset

In *Sagrada Reset*, one of the main characters possesses the ability to reset the world to a point in the last three days she has 'saved' at, which includes resetting her own memories.

Until she meets Kei, nothing changes after the reset as she is unable to know it ever happened. Yet she does understand how her power works despite never being able to witness it and she has been using it unsuccessfully for years.

At first, I thought everyone with an ability would just know what their ability is due to the setting, but in later episodes we hear of an incident where someone was injured using their ability for the first time, not knowing what it was, which suggests this is not the case.

So how *did* Haruki know what her power was before meeting Kei?

Answer (score 1):

As it is shown that other characters are unaware of their abilities, it is indeed a problem that there is no explanation of why Haruki knows hers.

Having just finished watching the series, I can with a good amount of certainty confirm the anime does not inform us of the answer. I would hope a light novel reader could find some quotes to give a definitive answer, but for now, the [fandom wiki](https://sagrada-reset.fandom.com/wiki/Misora_Haruki) offers this explanation under trivia:

> It´s implied that she knows her ability thanks to the Bureau, due to the fact that it was shown that one of the functions of the organization is to inform and help to understand their abilities to the people that develop one and stop any possible damage caused by the first activation of the ability.
>
> It's also possible that Haruki knows her ability thanks to her previous interactions with Sumire Sōma at the beginning of the series since she and the witch are able to notice the resets before they happen.

Though [tvtropes.org](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/SagradaReset) says this:

> The same way Asai Kei is aware of his unalterable memory ability: It's explicitly stated that all power-holders are aware on some level of their abilities and how exactly they work, whether they use them or not.

Like the other quote, this is unsubstantiated, but definitely worth looking into. I don't recall anything like this being stated, but it's possible I simply forgot it.

Due to the conflicting info we're getting here, it would be extremely helpful if someone could pull quotes directly from the light novels to get the real answer. Unfortunately, I have not read those, so this answer is the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the time travel girl explains to her. That is the only explanation I could think of, but yeah, the time travel girl we meet at the first episode tells her about her ability.

Comment: By time travel girl do you mean someone other than Haruki who has a time related power?